# "sdclt.exe /config" fails with unspecified error

Tags: windows-7, windows-backup

When using the "Backup and Restore" page from the control panel, I can see no backup has been set up, so I click "Set up backup":

[image: control panel page: backup and restore]

this results in the error (given here in text form for search engines):

```
[Window Title]
C:\Windows\system32\sdclt.exe

[Content]
C:\Windows\system32\sdclt.exe

Unspecified error
```

[image: error message]

after a UAC prompt (actually SuRun in my case).

When attempting to start `C:\Windows\System32\sdclt.exe /config` straight from an admin command prompt, nothing happens either. And by nothing I mean that no process is lingering afterwards.

Sysinternals' `procmon` shows that the process starts briefly, but ends on its own.

The only events in the event viewer that could be related (by time and context) are from sources `VSS` and `Backup`:

- `The Block Level Backup Engine service has stopped.` (`Backup`)
- `The VSS service is shutting down due to idle timeout.` (`VSS`)

those are informational, though. And yes, VSS is not disabled and it's working, too.

What's wrong here and how can I fix it?

Additional notes:

- This is a Windows 7 x64 with latest patches applied.
- The command `C:\Windows\System32\sdclt.exe /BLBBACKUPWIZARD` runs without problem, as opposed to the `C:\Windows\system32\sdclt.exe /config` (started as `%windir%\\system32\\sdclt.exe /configure`) which causes the unspecified error.

Comment: This problem still persists.